# How to rate limit ajax requests?

Tags: javascript

My user interface is currently wide open.

Particularly, there are some elements, each of which can be deleted separately by the user.  If the user hits the delete button repeatedly, an ajax request will be fired repeatedly.

Is rate limiting a standard practice that I should implement or is it OK to give the user wide open access to this?

Comment: Perhaps a delete all button that would prevent the user mashing on the button?

Comment: The same record could be being accessed at the same time when the button is clicked in rapid succession, might cause an error on DB

Comment: Figure out what is exactly is happening first. Are the requests not completing? If an ajax request doesn't complete you should try logging the error first.

Comment: It sounds like the protocol you have established between the client and the server is not "thread-safe", so multiple parallel requests trip it up. If that's true, you should make it so that each request is totally independent of anything else that might be going on. Neither rate limiting nor a bigger server are going to fix what might fundamentally be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is part client issue, part server issue. Some standard solution is to:

- adjust the interface to not allow the user to submit specific action too often (do it in JS eg. to disable abili to submit request to delete one thing twice),
- rate limiting on the server is usually not necessary, but could be useful,

Take StackOverflow as an example: when you downvote an answer, you are not able to downvote it again, and when you are eg. submitting comments, you need to wait couple seconds between submissions.

As far as errors are concerned... You may be hitting one of several categories of problems. For example:

- connectivity issues (lack of connection, wonky connection, or very slow connection),
- internal client limitation (like number of concurrent requests has reached maximum allowed),
- other, server-side limitations (rate limiting, requests blocking each other etc.),

Comment: SO does this so you cannot spam votes because it is *undesirable behavior*. It's not like if they let you spam there was going to be a technical problem.

Comment: @Jon: Exactly what I think was the primary idea. But do not underestimate the power of multiple repeated requests. I would say some "fanatic" users, if numerous, could bring the site to the edge of its capacity.

Comment: @pure_code.mom: I was rather thinking about disabling delete button for items that were already requested to be deleted (eg. you have clicked delete button next to the post, so hide the button until you get response from the server).

Answer (score 3):

You could group user requests in a queue. Then, check that queue from time to time for new requests to send.
So, the user interface will append actions to execute and you would be able to control how often you send them. You could prevent an action from being appended if it already is in the queue.
Also, this way you could modify your code to accept a list of actions to execute.

This is a general description that could be implemented in JavaScript using functions such as `setTimeout`.